# Can I access super properties in Java like I can in C#?

Tags: java

So, I'm working on a project and I was trying to have a property of a subclass return the value of the super class.

I.E

```
public class Parent
{
   BaseType m_Type;
}

public class Child extends Parent
{
   BaseType m_Type
   {
      return super.m_Type;
   }
}
```

Essentially that's the pattern I would use in C#. However, that doesn't seem to work in Java so I was wondering if there were a similar way to accomplish the same feat. If not, no big deal, I'll just create methods I guess. Just seems like cruft.

Comment: [everything](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) you need to know.

Comment: @matt except that page only talks about methods (like property accessors), not fields ;)

Comment: @Eidenai was it really easier to post that question rather than simply run your code and see if it works ?

Comment: @alfasin He did run his code and explicitly said it didn't work.

Comment: "However, that doesn't seem to work in Java" can we see your Java code?

Comment: @alfasin I don't think I have Java installed so it wasn't. Are you confusing me with OP?

Comment: @Taelsin the code "won't work" because of compilation errors. Once he fixes the constructor he can see if it works or not and if there's a compilation error - what does it say.

Comment: @CompuChip yeah sorry - corrected.

Comment: @alfasin no worries, not even sure why I was reading this question. Probably because of `C#` in the title :)

Comment: The page describes **member** access and use methods for examples, but fields behave the same way. I am not surprised the examples they provide are limited. Plus if you read, _You can also use super to refer to a hidden fields_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but the member needs to be protected or public:

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {   
        B b = new B();
        b.print();
    }

    public static class A {
        protected int member = 1;
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("A: "+member);
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        protected int member = 2;
        public void print(){
            super.print();
            System.out.println("B: "+member);
            System.out.println("C: "+super.member);
        }
    }
}
```

> A: 1
>
> B: 2
>
> C: 1

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I'm that inept. Thanks.